# Array formula to sum the value of each element

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the formula I have to apply to a cell in several rows in an Excel sheet:

(this one is for row 20, there could be 200+ rows)

```
=(
    Z20*Z$11*Z$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AA20*AA$11*AA$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AB20*AB$11*AB$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AC20*AC$11*AC$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AD20*AD$11*AD$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AE20*AE$11*AE$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AF20*AF$11*AF$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AG20*AG$11*AG$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AH20*AH$11*AH$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AI20*AI$11*AI$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AJ20*AJ$11*AJ$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AK20*AK$11*AK$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AL20*AL$11*AL$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AM20*AM$11*AM$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AN20*AN$11*AN$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20+
    AO20*AO$11*AO$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20
)/1000
```

I tried to use an array formula to make this a bit neater, e.g.

```
=(Z20:AO20*Z$11:AO$11*Z$9:AO$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20)/1000
```

However the value comes out wrong, and I think this is because the value is being multiplied at each element rather than added as I would want.

(I'm also aware that this might not be doing anything like I think it is!)

**Is there a way to make an array formula sum its element values?**

(note: a pivot table is not possible here)

Answer (score 0):

As frequently happens, I found the answer after I asked the question:

```
=SUM(Z20:AO20*Z$11:AO$11*Z$9:AO$9*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20)/1000
```

Comment: For a version which doesn't need "array entry" try using SUMPRODUCT like this 
=SUMPRODUCT(Z20:AO20,Z$11:AO$11,Z$9:AO$9)*VLOOKUP(V20,R5:T8,3,FALSE)*X20/1000

Comment: Great - will try that also!

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is a much better way to go. If this were an answer I would accept it! Thanks for your help.